# How to remove last character from grep output?

Tags: grep, text-processing

I have a text file with following content in it (for example):

```
In first line the "One", second"Two " & " Three " and also"Four    ". 
In second line also nested "foo "bar" baz""zoo" patterns.
```

I tried to had all strings between a pair of quotes and finally I ended up by this command:

```
grep -Po '"\K[^"]+"' file
```

What this command gave me is as following:

```
One"
Two "
 Three "
Four    "
foo "
 baz"
zoo"
```

And **what I want** from above result as my desired output would be:

```
One
Two 
 Three 
Four    
foo 
 baz
zoo
```

Please someone help me to remove the last `"` from the above `grep` output. I don't want to remove spaces from the output. I don't have any words which expanded to multiline. e.g:

```
... "foo "bar" ba
z""zoo" ...
```

Please, please don't suggest me I can use multiple commands, I know I can. I'm ask you if I can do it with grep and its options alone?

Comment: But regular expression matches are greedy so just searching for [^"]+ without the trailing " should be enough shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be possible through the below grep one-liner.

```
$ grep -oP '"\K[^"]+(?="(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)' file
One
Two 
 Three 
Four    
foo 
 baz
zoo
```

Another hacky one through PCRE verb [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26272200/3297613),

```
$ grep -oP '[^"]+(?=(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*[^"]*$)(*SKIP)(*F)|[^"]+' file
One
Two 
 Three 
Four    
foo 
 baz
zoo
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` if you can not solve it with  `grep`

```
awk -F\" '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) {gsub(/ /,"");print $i}}' file
One
Two
Three
Four
foo
baz
zoo
```

```
awk -F\" '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i}'
One
Two
 Three
Four
foo
 baz
zoo
```

Comment: @KasiyA Not all can be solved easy with `grep`. Do you not have  `awk`?